# Conectar Qt con Github?

Tags: c++, qt, github

**Hola!** ¿Que tal? Actualmente desarrollo software con Qt pero comenzaré con los **"Controles de Versiones"** ya que estaré trabajando en equipo, pero no logro conectarme directamente con **Github**, lo que quiero es que si; **yo estoy modificando un archivo Ej: "Sistema.cpp" otro miembro del equipo no pueda abrirlo hasta que yo acabe de modificar ese archivo.**

**Les agradezco mucho la ayuda.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justamente la filosofía de Git es lo contrario a lo que estás planteando. En Git se permite cualquier modificación entre más de un usuario de un mismo archivo, esto elimina la idea de un trabajo secuencial, primero yo hago unos cambios y cuando están listos recién lo puede tomar el siguiente usuario. En Git el problema se traslada al que quiere subir un cambio sobre algo que ya fue modificado, ahí entra a jugar el "Merge". La respuesta rápida es con Git no lo puedes hacer, o al menos no de una forma estándar.

Comment: Conoces algún Control de versiones que trabaje así en Ubuntu? La mayoría de los que he consultado trabajan como Git y gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si no me equivoco el [SVN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)) puede trabajar con esta filosofía que planteas..

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio Moracho, revisaré. 
Me di por vencido hace rato y estuve buscando como trabaja Git y creo que es mejor a lo que estaba buscando.